# Get the only records specified in filter condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

What I am looking for is the query that can return only selected packages filtered by the product id.

Even if I select only one product, query should return only record that is solely defined in where clause and should not return records if that specified product id is also involved in other packages as well.

Tables examples

Packages Table

```
    id  package_name           
------  ------------

     2  STANDARD               
     3  BUSINESS               
     5  BASIC                  
     6  CLASSIC
```

package_product table

```
    id  package_id  product_id  
------  ----------  ------------

     2           3            52
     3         230            52
     4         230            53
     5           2            52
     6           2            53
     7           5            52
     8           5            53
```

product table

```
    id  product_name          
------  ----------------------

    52  Logo Design           
    53  Website Design        
    54  Business Card Design
```

Query I am trying to use

```
SELECT p.id, p.package_name, p.package_price, pp.product_id
FROM package_product pp INNER JOIN packages p ON p.id = pp.package_id
WHERE pp.product IN (52, 53)
```

Result what i get

```
    id  package_name  package_price  product_id  

------  ------------  -------------  ------------

         3  BUSINESS      139                      52
       230  ULTIMATE      1149                     52
       230  ULTIMATE      1149                     53
         2  STANDARD      89                       52
         2  STANDARD      89                       53
         5  BASIC         265                      52
         5  BASIC         265                      53
```

What I am looking for

```
    id  package_name  package_price  product_id  

------  ------------  -------------  ------------

       230  ULTIMATE      1149                     52
       230  ULTIMATE      1149                     53
         2  STANDARD      89                       52
         2  STANDARD      89                       53
         5  BASIC         265                      52
         5  BASIC         265                      53
```

Comment: Your current output is what you should be expecting here.  Can you give us logic by which the `BUSINESS` record appearing first should not appear in your output?

Comment: Current output pulls out all the packages related with any of the product specified in filter i.e. 52,53 . What I am expecting here to pull out only records that can show me rows in which product 52 and 53 both combined form the expected rows

Comment: What if you append `HAVING COUNT(p.id) > 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may join to a subquery which imposes the restriction that a matching package have both 52 and 53 products:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.package_name,
    p.package_price,
    pp.product_id
FROM package_product pp
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT package_id
    FROM package_product
    WHERE product_id IN (52, 53)
    GROUP BY package_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) = 2
) t
    ON pp.package_id = t.package_id
INNER JOIN packages p
    ON p.id = pp.package_id;
```

[image]

### Demo

The subquery aliased as `t` above finds those packages having both the 52 and 53 products.  Used as an inner join, it filters off non matching packages.

Comment: Thanks Tim, this query some how conclude to my solution but in case I have more than 2 products than I am getting all the packages which are also involved twice in the table. So have added some extra lines to get rows filtered GROUP BY p.id HAVING COUNT(p.id) = 2. Cheers :)